# How do I get PendingIntent using the MvvmCross 5 IMvxNavigationService?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a method I used in MvvmCross 4.x that was used with the `NotificationCompat.Builder` to set a `PendingIntent` of a notification to display a ViewModel when the notification is clicked by the user. I'm trying to convert this method to use the MvvmCross 5.x `IMvxNavigationService` but can't see how to setup the presentation parameters, and get a `PendingIntent` using the new navigation API.

```
private PendingIntent RouteNotificationViewModelPendingIntent(int controlNumber, RouteNotificationContext notificationContext, string stopType)
{
    var request = MvxViewModelRequest<RouteNotificationViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest();
    request.ParameterValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "controlNumber", controlNumber.ToString() },
        { "notificationContext", notificationContext.ToString() },
        { "stopType", stopType }
    };
    var translator = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidViewModelRequestTranslator>();
    var intent = translator.GetIntentFor(request);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);

    return PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context,
                                     _notificationId,
                                     intent,
                                     PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
}
```

The RouteNotificationViewModel does appear when I click the notification but `Prepare` and `Initialize` are not being called. What is necessary to convert this method from MvvmCross 4.x style of navigation to MvvmCross 5.x style of navigation?

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to receive the intent?

Comment: There is no code receiving the intent. Android creates the activity when I click on the notification. That part is working, but `Prepare` and `Initialize` do not get called by MvvmCross when the activity is shown by Android. This all worked in MvvmCross 4 assuming the navigation parameters were manually serialized. Now in MvvmCross 5 the navigation parameters are serialized differently.

Comment: Can you open an issue in the repo for this? This scenario is not currently supported for v5 Navigation I'm afraid. But we're working actively on the MvxNavigationService.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2418) the GitHub issue for anyone following this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do this in MvvmCross 5+ but it's not as clean as it previously was.

For starters you want to specify the singleTop launch mode for your activity:

```cs
[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ...)]
public class MainActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity
```

Generate the notification PendingIntent like this:

```cs
var intent = new Intent(Context, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
// Putting an extra in the Intent to pass data to the MainActivity
intent.PutExtra("from_notification", true);
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Context, notificationId, intent, 0);
```

Now there are two places to handle this Intent from MainActivity while still allowing the use of MvvmCross navigation service:

If the app was not running while the notification was clicked then `OnCreate` will be called.

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    if (bundle == null && Intent.HasExtra("from_notification"))
    {
        // The notification was clicked while the app was not running. 
        // Calling MvxNavigationService multiple times in a row here won't always work as expected. Use a Task.Delay(), Handler.Post(), or even an MvvmCross custom presentation hint to make it work as needed.
    }
}
```

If the app was running while the notification was clicked then `OnNewIntent` will be called.

```cs
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.HasExtra("from_notification"))
    {
        // The notification was clicked while the app was already running.
        // Back stack is already setup.
        // Show a new fragment using MvxNavigationService.
    }
}
```